# ADO VBA Connecting to an Azure SQL database without installing a driver

Tags: sql-server, vba, azure, connection-string, ado

I am using this connection string to connect to an Azure SQL database from inside Excel and everything works fine because I have installed Microsoft's `OLE DB` driver.

I was wondering if it is possible to connect without installing this driver? I have many users that should do it and it is not practical to ask IT for many installations. The users themselves are not a local admin on their Windows 10 so I am looking for a workaround

```
'connection string (azure)
Public Const sConnectionStringAzure = "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;" & _
                        "DataTypeCompatibility=80;" & _
                        "Server=tcp:myserver.database.example.net,1433;" & _
                        "Database=mydatabase;" & _
                        "Uid=BasicUser@myserver;" & _
                        "Pwd={abc};" & _
                        "Encrypt=yes;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

Comment: A little confused that you don't want to use OLE DB driver to connect to Azure SQL database, as I know, no matter which way connect to Azure SQL database, we all need the driver support. We still need install it on local machines.

Comment: I guess I was hoping there was a pre-installed driver on Windows 10 that could be used?

Comment: No, there isn't such a  pre-installed driver on Windows 10 which we can use to connect to Azure SQL database.

Comment: Hi @Ibo, If the answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, no matter which way connect to Azure SQL database, we all need the driver support. We still need install it on local machines.

Most tools which integrate the driver in it so that we can use it directly without install the SQL driver again.

There isn't a pre-installed driver on Windows 10 which we can use it connect to Azure SQL database.

HTH.